# What would cause these bubbles in texture?

Tags: paint, texture

I recently had a contractor out doing work on my bathroom, including re-texturing walls and painting.

When we 'moved back in', I noticed the walls are littered with these little 'holes' or bubbles and not sure what would have caused it.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's either poorly prepared compound or poor application technique.

I assume you're asking this because the are finished with the work.  If that's the case, this is substandard work, in my opinion at least, and should be corrected.

Comment: Air bubbles in the mix. +1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jack!

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't intentional? Did you discuss the finish texture you wanted prior to him working on it? Are you sure he is done, or is he just waiting for this to thoroughly dry before coming back in for a final coat? All that said, he likely used a drill motor to mix his mud and was in a hurry, so he used too high of a speed and pulled air into the mud.